# ggplot2 move horizontal y label to the top?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I move the y label up to the top? (In this case, right bellow 35)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ylab("First line \nSecond Line") + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

Thanks,

Ignacio

Comment: Have you read the help for `element_text()`, by any chance? I'm not sure if it's enough for your purpose, but you can move an element up manually through the `vjust` argument (setting it to 1 would move the label to the upper end). BTW: You're not the first one to ask this question today.

Comment: `vjust=1` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka that works

Comment: @Heroka please post your comment as an answer... it solves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0,vjust=1)
```